# Converting time of dictionary value from UTC to EDT and alignment of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert the Last Updated time to EDT. Also, fix the alignment of the id and Values row.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

state = input("Enter two character state code eg: NY, CA: ")
url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/states?state={}".format(state)

result = requests.get(url)
dataobj = result.json()

# Only intersted in showing these keys and their associated values:
interested_keys = ['state','positive','dataQualityGrade','negative','pending','hospitalizedCurrently','hospitalizedCumulative','inIcuCurrently','inIcuCumulative','onVentilatorCurrently','onVentilatorCumulative','recovered','death','total','dateModified']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataobj, orient='index',columns=['Values']).loc[interested_keys]
interested_now = ['State','Positive Cases','Data Quality Grade','Negative Cases','Pending Cases', 'Currently Hospitalized','Hospitalized Cumulative','In ICU Currently','In ICU Cumulative','On Ventilator Currently','On Ventilator Cumulative','Recovered','Deaths','Total Cases (Pos + Neg)','Last Updated']

df['id'] = interested_now

df.set_index('id' , inplace = True)
df.replace(to_replace=[None], value="N/A", inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: It's called the **[con](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:con)vid19**

Answer (score 0):

So, the result of the `df = ...` line is a series where the index is the dictionary keys from dataobj. So, first subset the series by the old index, then assign new values to the index.

```
df2 = df.loc[interested_keys]
df2.index = interested_now
```

Output

```
>>>df2
                                        Values
State                                       NY
Positive Cases                          282143
Data Quality Grade                           B
Negative Cases                          495425
Pending Cases                             None
Currently Hospitalized                   13524
Hospitalized Cumulative                  57103
In ICU Currently                          5016
In ICU Cumulative                         None
On Ventilator Currently                   None
On Ventilator Cumulative                  None
Recovered                                23887
Deaths                                   16599
Total Cases (Pos + Neg)                 777568
Last Updated              2020-04-25T04:00:00Z
```

Comment: The header of the first column is gone now. I want to set to something like "Parameter"

Comment: That is the index, not a column. Use the ```rename``` method of the ```index```. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.rename.html